Question regarding Resource view in .NET MAUI Scheduler (SfScheduler)
I need to add to the scheduler, namely on top of the time lines of the day these resources, which in my case will denote a certain type to which the appointments will be attached.
I have not found such solutions in the documentation, is there any way to add such resources? If so, how? Thanks in advance for the answer!)
